Omitting 不可 in sentences starting with 非
汉语熟语小词典（２０１０，北京）５７页 for 花里胡哨 has the following usage example:
妹妹看到柜台里那些花里胡哨的玩具，非催着我给她买几个, some users would expect 催着我...(without 非), or maybe it could say 非(催着)我给她买几个不可,that is 不可 has been omitted.

The following sentences have the same or similar meaning in Chinese. They are mostly colloquial languages and, therefore, may not have the exact logical structure in appearance.
(1) 她非催着我给她买玩具不可。
(2) 她非催着我给她买玩具。
(3) 她非催着我给她买玩具才行。
(4) 她催着我非给她买玩具不行。
(5) 她催着我非给她买玩具才行。
(6) 她催着我不给她买玩具不行。
(7) 她催着我给她买玩具才行。
This is not a comprehensive list. There may be more examples.

Here is another classic example of a "critical" character whose meaning is implied but is missing.
非催着我给她买几个(不可) with 非。。不可 meaning "insisted on 。。"
As for alternative ways to rewrite the sentence, your first suggestion 催着我给她买几个 has almost the same meaning, but as it is without 非， it loses out on the persistent request.
The second suggestion is equivalent to explicitly writing out 非。。不可 which retains the sentence's original meaning.

In this case, yes, it can be omitted because the meaning here is "一定要某件事情發生" or "have to make something happen."
But the interesting thing is, when after "非" is a thing, 不可 can't be omitted, or its meaning might change a bit.
For example, 我非要那個東西不可 (I have to have that thing), if you omit 不可: 我非要那個東西(I just want to have that thing).

Answers from @r13 and @summer7 already explained the meaning very well. And here are some tips about the linguistics of this sentence:
Considering the structure of the sentence, 非……不可 is a special pattern in a sentence just like how you use "not only ... but also ..." in English (but the meaning is different though.)
Meaningwise, this is a double negative in which “非” and “不可” are both expressing nagation. In this sentence, the double nagative is used to emphasize a meaning of "this is the only way of ..."

非...不可 is a patterned phrase that indicates someone is "insisting on getting things (非) his/her way without room for compromising (不可)". Note that "不可" refers to the non-compromisable attitude - "不達目地不罷休" only, which often can be dropped without altering the context of the sentence.

"非要"我给她买几个(不可) = "一定要"我给她买几个(不然就不罷休).

Note: I think "要" makes better sense than "催着" in this sentence.
